# bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory on Kali Linux

Tags: python, linux, kali-linux, sqlmap

I'm using Kali linux. When I tryied `sqlmap`, I got errof which is

```
zsh: /usr/bin/sqlmap: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory
```

It seems there is not existing python3. But it showed weird.

```
apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.8.6-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
```

How can I fix and use sqlmap?

For reference.

```
which python
/usr/bin/python
```

```
which python2
/usr/bin/python2
```

```
which python3
python3 not found
```

```
python -V
Python 3.8.6
```

```
python2 -V
python 2.7.18
```

```
python3 -V
zsh: command not found: python3
```

Comment: /usr_bin/python3? Really?

Comment: Otherwise, it looks as if python3 is installed as plain python. So just create a link for python3 pointing to python, and you should be all set.

Comment: `usr_bin` is hilarious. The symbolic link could work.

Comment: Sorry. ```usr_bin``` it's typo. 
```usr/bin``` is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a symbolic link pointing your `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python3`.

`ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: It's the other way around:
```ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python```